# Next Auth Authentication with firebase Adapter not working on Next JS 13

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

i'm trying to implement an Auth functionality to my Next JS 13 app using Next Auth and firebase. but when i add everything and run the code it throws an error of

> error - FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists with different options or config (app/duplicate-app).`.

When i use the firbaseconfig directly to the adapter it works. but when i import it from `firebase.js` file it throws the above error.

`firebase.js`

```
import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

const app = getApps.length > 0 ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { db, storage, app };
```

`[...nextauth].js`

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";
import { db } from "../../../firebase";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter(db),
  // ...
});
```

help me out. ever since i upgraded to next JS 13 it's been a hell.

only update in firebase.js

```
const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

export const app =
  getApps().length > 0 ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

the error is pointed to this location in `[...nextauth].js

`adapter: FirestoreAdapter(db),` towards the db entry

Comment: Hi, I would avoid sharing personal information and api keys. Just leave them blank to avoid problems. Right now, you anyone can use the info you provided to cause problems  or takeover your app.

Comment: thanks, i haven't realized about that

Answer (score 1):

The `getApps` is a function but you are using `.length` without calling it.
Try:

```
const app = getApps().length > 0 ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// getApps.length    => 0 ✕
// getApps().length  => 1 ✔️
```

Comment: i did that but same thing happened

Comment: it's pointing me to the `adapter: FirestoreAdapter(db),` in `[...nextauth].js` file . the part where db is inserted

Comment: @MohammedBekele did you try restarting dev server? Also are you calling `initializeApp()` from anywhere else?

Comment: i restarted it several times, and i'm only initializing it form one place

Comment: @MohammedBekele can you update your code with the latest code that you have? Have you tried figuring out which part causes issue by maybe commenting out some code.

Comment: i uploaded it. i didn't make any changes to it tho

Comment: Is this on Github by chance? Or would be able to share a minimal reproduction on https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: i don't think it's a bug, it may be some thing i'm missing to do

Comment: @MohammedBekele if you don't share complete code no one would be able to figure that out. Can you post a minimal reproduction?

Comment: i only used auth functions in the code above. when i pass the whole config directly inside `firestoreAdapter()` it works. the problem is that when i pass it with the import `db`